# Packaged python lib `site` fails with pythonnet

Tags: python, path, clr, python-import, python.net

It appears that importing the [`pythonnet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonnet/2.2.1) library `clr` isn't compatible with the standard library [`site`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html)

- Is this an issue with `clr` or `site`?

***NB*** *`site.abs__file__()` is called by `site.main()`*

```
In [1]: import site
   ...: site.abs__file__()
   ...:

In [2]: import clr

In [3]: site.abs__file__()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-17ed7fe71c4c> in <module>()
----> 1 site.abs__file__()

C:\Users\mcfarlal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site.pyc in abs__file__()
     92             continue   # don't mess with a PEP 302-supplied __file__
     93         try:
---> 94             m.__file__ = os.path.abspath(m.__file__)
     95         except (AttributeError, OSError):
     96             pass

TypeError: type does not support setting attribute
```

## Debugging

If we look into the function `site.abs__file__` it is precisely the following that fails:

```
import os
import sys
clr.__file__ = os.path.abspath(m.__file__)
```

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue31798

Comment: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/559